# I am wanting to format my X Axis in GGPLOT to be years and months not days

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

in my ggplot call i am plotting as follows the X Axis just shows every singke days date like this 20171130 etc in the label and I want my lables to be like Nov-17 ,Dec-17 ETC

```
# Invoke a ggplot with date vs. sessions data, segmented by device category
  ggplot(data = gaDataExt, mapping = aes(x = date, y = pageviews, group = 1, color = deviceCategory) ) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x = "date", y = "Pageviews by Device Category") +
  labs(title = "Andy D) Users by Device Category", x="Date", y="Total Page views") +
  ylim(0,NA)
```

Sombody suggested to us elubridate which  didnt seem to be exactly waht I was looking for

```
gaDataExt %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date),
         month = year(date)) %>% 
  group_by(deviceCategory) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, pageviews)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(deviceCategory~.) +
  theme_bw()
```

here is my current output that you can see is all clustered on the date Axis and i would like to display just the month and year on that axis

[image]

```
gaDataExt %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date),
         month = year(date)) %>% 
  group_by(deviceCategory) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, pageviews)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(deviceCategory~.) +
  theme_bw()
```

was what somebody suggested but that didnt seem to work

here is a head of the dataframe i am trting to plot

```
> head(gaData_User)
        date          userType deviceCategory   country            region        city users
1 30-11-2017       New Visitor        desktop Australia          Victoria   Melbourne     2
2 30-11-2017       New Visitor         mobile Australia   New South Wales      Sydney     1
3 30-11-2017       New Visitor         mobile Australia          Victoria   Melbourne     2
4 30-11-2017 Returning Visitor        desktop Australia          Victoria   Melbourne     1
5 30-11-2017 Returning Visitor        desktop Australia          Victoria Warrnambool     1
6 30-11-2017 Returning Visitor        desktop Australia Western Australia       Perth     1
```

Comment: Why don't you update your original question? If someone suggested solution, but it wasn't what you were looking for then please clarify your original question

Comment: Please, can you explain what the purpose is of `mutate(date = ymd(date),         month = year(date))`? Is this really intended to create a `month` column which contains the year?

Comment: And again, please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], in particular a sample data set to reproduce the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please, try

    `ggplot(data = gaDataExt, mapping = aes(x = lubridate::floor_date(date, "month"), y = pageviews, group = 1, color = deviceCategory) ) + 
      geom_col() +
      theme_bw() + 
      labs(x = "date", y = "Pageviews by Device Category") +
      labs(title = "Andy D) Users by Device Category", x="Date", y="Total Page views") +
      ylim(0,NA)`

Comment: Error in `[[.default`(object, name, exact = TRUE) : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: Please, double check your edit. You have posted `head(gaData_User)` which doesn't contain a `pageviews` column while your sample codes use `gaDataExt` as data and map `pageviews` on the y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `scale_x_date`, one simple example.

```
last_month <- Sys.Date() - 0:29
df <- data.frame(
  date = last_month,
  price = runif(30)
 )

ggplot(df, aes(date, price)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m")
```

[image]

Comment: ok so last_month <- Sys.Date() - 0:29
df <- data.frame(
  date = last_month,
  price = runif(30)
 )